# NPM/Yarn equivalent for Python's "pip download && pip install --no-index --find-links"

Tags: python, node.js, npm, pip, yarnpkg

Let's say I want to download tarballs of a package (or list of packages) **with all of it's dependencies (and their sub-dependencies)**, and then install all of the packages from the downloaded tarballs.

The installation should install the packages directly from the tarballs **without any access to the internet.**

This method can be achieved on Python using the following steps:

1. `pip download <package-name>` / `pip download -r <path-to-requirements.txt>` to download all the tarballs of the packages and their sub-dependencies
2. `pip install <package-name> --no-index --find--links <tarballs-folder-url>` / 
   `pip install -r <path-to-requirements.txt> --no-index --find--links <tarballs-folder-url>` to install packages (and their dependencies) directly from the tarballs **without any access to the internet**.

I want to achieve the same method with NPM/Yarn, without any usage of local cache (i.e. the cache folder under AppData / user's home), npmjs.org, private registry (like Verdaccio), Yarn's offline-mirror and so on.

Is it possible to do so with NPM/Yarn? 
I don't mind to use custom packages for this purpose.